# Drafts posts to Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't for the life of me work out how (or whether it's possible) to post a draft to the Facebook API. I don't mean a dark post as these can't be edited, but an actual draft (I believe these are only available when posting as a Page rather than as an individual).

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you are correct when saying:

> I believe these are only available when posting as a Page rather than as an individual

On the other hand, there is a **workaround** for your request.

**The easier way to do what you want** would be to post as `Only Me` (Private post).

[image: only me]

You can later come back, edit and maybe re-edit the post and finally publish it the way you want it.

[image: public post]

---

If you are interested on the step by step way to post a draft on a page please have a look at [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95782/117311) over at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/